# Swap two adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba

I really can't get this simple code to work.

```
Sub SwapNumbers()

Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, tempB As Integer

x = Range("B3")

y = Range("C3")

tempB = x

Range("C3") = x

Range("B3") = y

End Sub
```

How do I remove the specific cell and make it to two adjacent cells?

Thanks!

Comment: so what triggers this, does the user select the cells and hit a button?  we need more info.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes sorry. The user selects the two cells that he/she wants to swap and clicks the button.

Comment: What would you want to happen if the user has selected more than 2 cells? Is it ok if the adjacent cells are one above the other? What about two cells that are not adjacent? There are a lot of things that you need to consider that the user *might* do that would require different actions.

Comment: I got a solution but thank you for saying this. I am new to coding and stuff like your comment only improves my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it. You might want to also check that the cells contain integers.

```
Sub Swap()

Dim tempB As Long

With Selection
    If .Rows.Count = 1 And .Count = 2 And .Cells(1).Column = .Cells(2).Column - 1 Then
        tempB = .Cells(1).Value
        .Cells(1).Value = .Cells(2).Value
        .Cells(2).Value = tempB
    Else
        MsgBox "Select 2 adjacent cells in the same row"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

This will work with any two cells, regardless if they are connected or not:

```
Sub swap()
    With Selection
        If .Count <> 2 Then Exit Sub
        Dim arr(1 To 2) As Variant

        Dim x As Long
        x = 1

        Dim cl As Range
        For Each cl In Selection
            arr(x) = cl
            x = x + 1
        Next cl

        x = 2

        For Each cl In Selection
            cl.Value = arr(x)
            x = x - 1
        Next cl
     End With

End Sub
```